# Why are autoencoders for dimension reduction symmetrical?

Tags: neural-network, dimensionality-reduction, autoencoder

I'm not an expert in autoencoders or neural networks by any means, so forgive me if this is a silly question.

For the purpose of dimension reduction or visualizing clusters in high dimensional data, we can use an autoencoder to create a (lossy) 2 dimensional representation by inspecting the output of the network layer with 2 nodes. For example, with the following architecture, we would inspect the output of the third layer

$[X] \rightarrow N_1=100 \rightarrow N_2=25 \rightarrow (N_3=2) \rightarrow N_4=25 \rightarrow N_5=100 \rightarrow [X]$

where $X$ is the input data and $N_l$ is the number of nodes in the $l$th layer.

Now, my question is, why do we want a symmetrical architecture? Doesn't a mirror of the deep 'compression' phase mean we might have a similarly complex 'decompression' phase resulting in a 2 node output which is not forced to be very intuitive? In other words, wouldn't having a simpler decoding phase result in the output of the layer with 2 nodes necessarily being simpler too?

My thinking here is that the less complex the decompression phase, the simpler (more linear?) the 2D representation has to be. A more complex decompression phase would allow a more complex 2D representation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no specific constraint on the symmetry of an autoencoder.

At the beginning, people tended to enforce such symmetry to the maximum: not only the layers were symmetrical, but also the **weights** of the layers in the encoder and decoder where **shared**. This is not a requirement, but it [allows to use certain loss functions (i.e. RBM score matching)](https://www.quora.com/Is-weight-sharing-required-for-an-autoencoder/answer/Ian-Goodfellow?srid=ikXo) and can act as [regularization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/154867/40048), as you effectively reduce by half the number of parameters to optimize. Nowadays, however, I think no one imposes encoder-decoder weight sharing.

About architectural symmetry, it is **common** to find the same number of layers, the same type of layers and the same layer sizes in encoder and decoder, but **there is no need** for that.

For instance, in convolutional autoencoders, in the past it was very common to find convolutional layers in the encoder and *deconvolutional* layers in the decoder, but now you normally see upsampling layers in the decoder because they have less artefacts problems.

Answer (score 9):

Your question is definitely in place, however I found that any question in the format of "should I do X or Y in deep learning ?" has only one answer.

**Try them both**

Deep learning is a very empirical field, and if a non-symmetric auto-encoder works for your domain, then use it (and publish a paper)

Answer (score 4):

I did some extensive experimenting to address the asked question. My experiments indicated that the encoding path (left leg of the NN) should have less, but wider layers. I usually take half as many layers, but double the number of nodes for the encoding path. I have no explanation for this, just these configurations often led to faster convergence.