# Convolutional autoencoder - why keras example is asymmetry model?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, convolutional-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm looking on `keras` convolutional autoencoder example, and confused with the model structure:

```
import keras
from keras import layers

input_img = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

x = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

# at this point the representation is (4, 4, 8) i.e. 128-dimensional

x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = keras.Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

The last layer of the `encoder` contains `MaxPooling2D` layer and the first layer of the `decoder` starts with `Conv2D` layer.

1. Why it is not symmetry ? I assumed that if the last layer of the encoder is down sample layer that the first layer of the decoder will be up-sampling layer.
2. What is the advantage of building the model as `keras` publish (instead of using up-sampling as first layer of the decoder) ?
3. Is there a reason that some layers contains padding and other not ? (Is it because we want to get to same output size as the input size) ?

Comment: [This answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/23744/14675) may be helpful regarding your first point.